# Amazon RDS speed

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds

I would like to know if this is ok. I signed up for amazon RDS web service to speed up my PHP application. I have basic debian virtual server and some queries take 4s to execute. So I thought hosting on amazon's cloud could speed up the running time.
So I exported database, imported to amazon RDS and found out that running time is almost 2 times higher.

One of the reason could be type of account I have - free (db.t1.micro).
Second - I am in EU and availability zone is set to US-WEST-1 (for some reason I couldnt select EU). However, I checked only SQL execution time, without network time so the distance shouldnt matter in this case.

So is it slower than non-cloud solution just because of type of account? My database is not that big - around 25MB.

Comment: Have you tried optimizing your queries?

Comment: I honestly found the same type of thing. I was using the micro account and found the RDS interaction slow.  I switched to put the mysql database right on the EC2 and things were much faster. In my case, it could very well have been that I had not configured something correctly, but there was a definite speedup when the database was on EC2.

Comment: With only 25MB of data all instance types should work. You need to take a look at your queries.

Comment: @brechmos I checked EC2 but it looks like too much hassle - did I understood it correctly that first I need to install FTP and database as there is just plain instance of ubuntu? is there any quick way how to just start database and import existing one?

Comment: mysql/mysqld will have to be installed.  Not sure why FTP would have to be installed. What you can do is just dump the database from RDS and then upload to your new server (restore).  Probably wouldn't take more than an hour (depending on how much data you have and your skill level :-) ). It would be interesting to do some tests, then, and compare the speed difference. That should give you more info on whether it is query issues, machine or network latency.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why a database query could be slow:

- complexity of the query
- tables not set up well (e.g. no indexes)
- power of the machine it's running on (AWS micro instances are likely weaker than your laptop)
- network latency between database machine and client machine (I have a case on my hands in which the client does close to 1000 queries in a single page load; both the RDS instance and the web server are basically idle all the while, yet the page load is super slow (~2 secs) because close to 1000 queries need to traverse the AWS internal network between EC2 instance and RDS instance back and forth)

You need to figure out what of this applies to you and how you can mitigate it. There's no general answer for why something is slow.

Comment: In my case, I believe it was the last point (I had appropriate indexing etc).  I did a ton of checking including page generation speed tests (php), mysql profiling etc etc and it all seemed 'fast'. :-)

Comment: I dont claim my queries are well optimised. but that doesnt matter, as I use the very same queries on the very same database as on my virtual server. if optimisation was the case, then I am just comparing 2 non optimised queries. but even then, I would expect to execute non optimised query faster on amazanon than non optimised query on basic virtual server

Comment: @Michal You don't need to discuss with me, I'm just listing things which *may* be slow. :) You'll have to figure out what exactly the case is. Look at all available monitoring charts and figure it out. :)